# Array that store color maps flutter

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart, multidimensional-array, colors

¿How can we create an array to store colors in dart, with this structure style?

```
    "1":{
        "a": Colors.grey[800],
        "b": Colors.grey[800],
        "c": Colors.grey[800],
        "d": Colors.grey[800],
       },
   "2":{
        "a": Colors.grey[800],
        "b": Colors.grey[800],
        "c": Colors.grey[800],
        "d": Colors.grey[800],
       },
```

I created a map trying to achieve that

```
Map<String,  Color> btncolor = {
"a": Colors.grey[800],
"b": Colors.grey[800],
"c": Colors.grey[800],
"d": Colors.grey[800],
};
```

but it needs 3 arguments to have an index, and its not possible to do it.

```
Map<String, String,  Color> btncolor = {
   "1":{
        "a": Colors.grey[800],
        "b": Colors.grey[800],
        "c": Colors.grey[800],
        "d": Colors.grey[800],
       },
   "2":{
        "a": Colors.grey[800],
        "b": Colors.grey[800],
        "c": Colors.grey[800],
        "d": Colors.grey[800],
       },
  };
```

As im kinda new to Flutter coding any hint or help would be appreciated, ty.

Comment: I haven't understood what is the purpose. Can you explain this in detail?

Comment: I need to have 20 indexes each one with "a": Colors.grey[800], ,"b"Colors.grey[800], ,"c" Colors.grey[800], ,"d" Colors.grey[800],

Comment: its a trivia app that needs to have color changed often, im currently assigning one variable to text color, but I need an array for storing all 20 question and its (a,b,c,d) colors. only with a variable I can't control all of them separate

Comment: you need an array of 20 elements, where each element is ths map -> {
        "a": Colors.grey[800],
        "b": Colors.grey[800],
        "c": Colors.grey[800],
        "d": Colors.grey[800],
       }. Right ?

Comment: yes, so I look for the value like color: buttoncolors[index][option]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a List of 20 elements with the same element,(here the element is Map Object that maps String to Color), Try this,

```
Map<String,Color>  btnColorMap = {
        "a": Colors.grey[800],
        "b": Colors.grey[800],
        "c": Colors.grey[800],
        "d": Colors.grey[800],
       }

var list = List<Map>.filled(20, btnColorMap);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do that, change `Map<String, String, Color>` to `Map<String, Map<String, Color>>` as if you are telling dart that you want a map of maps. because the map constructor only takes 2 arguments.

so the final result should be like this:

```
Map<String, Map<String,  Color>> btncolor = {
   "1":{
        "a": Colors.grey[800],
        "b": Colors.grey[800],
        "c": Colors.grey[800],
        "d": Colors.grey[800],
       },
   "2":{
        "a": Colors.grey[800],
        "b": Colors.grey[800],
        "c": Colors.grey[800],
        "d": Colors.grey[800],
       },
  };
```